# I want some html element in my form that uniform.js has no effect

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-uniform

I am using uniform.js to beautify my html forms. But I want some of the HTML elements to not be modified by uniform.js.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more ? Uniform uses CSS selectors to select elements to be modified, so I don't understand what you need more than this kind of selection that permits you to select every element precisely. Please provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Uniform uses jquery and css to beautify html forms on document ready. suppose i use $(function(){ $("body").uniform(); });

Answer (score 1):

add a class to the objects you don't want to be attached to the uniform plugin, and use the jquery .not() selector.

like this: [How to remove uniform function on a specific select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349065/how-to-remove-uniform-function-on-a-specific-select)

Answer (score 0):

Search trough your files and delete the transformations you don't need.

Example (search for this):

```
$(function(){ $("YOURELEMENT").uniform(); });
```

And comment/delete it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the scenario is not same. suppose i use $(function(){ $("body").uniform(); }); Then all the form elements uses this plugin css. Now I don't want to use uniform only a specific element like a button which id is user_check. Other buttons will use uniform. Another question is that how will i make my html form elements unified when the contents are generated by an ajax response.