# How to remove uniform function on a specific select?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-uniform

i am using uniform js for changing the background images of checkbox, radio buttons, select box. For this i include jquery file, uniform library js file and another thing is a function of uniform js for initializing the function as

```
$(function(){
   $("input, select, textarea, button").uniform();
});
```

Here i got one issue, i want to clear this function at the specific portion of the content **where i do not want uniform function. then what procedure do i adopt for solving my problem?**

I do not have jsfiddle code for this code. If you need it i will let you know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function and set a class on items that you wish to omit the `uniform()` logic.

**DOM**:

```
<!-- This gets it -->
<select>
   <option>Foo</option>
</select>

<!-- This doesn't -->
<select class="noUniform">
    <option>Bar</option>
</select>
```

**JS**:

```
$(function(){
   $("input, select, textarea, button").not('.noUniform').uniform();
});
```

Comment: Will the bind function works here ?? or either i prefer your piece of code.

Comment: What if op has dozens or hundreds of elements that need the class applied?  And would you agree that supporting this down the road becomes a problem, since new elements which are added that don't have this class attribute will have `uniform` applied?  For that reason, I think a positive selector is almost always better than a negative one and here, the double-negative of `.not(.noUniform)` is semantically clumsy in my opinion.  No offense intended.

Comment: The simple fact that he's binding on tag names implies that they should be uniform by default, minus a handful of special cases. @Hassaan I don't see any binding here, just a function applied to the nodes. If you need it applied to nodes added after DOM ready, simply place the above logic in a function you can call after the new nodes are added.

Comment: Worked a charm. Thank you for providing this solution.

Comment: This link provides further info: https://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform/issues/150

Answer (score 1):

the attribute `data-no-uniform` set as `"true"` do the job

Answer (score 0):

According to Prestashop 1.6.x there is already omitting uniform implemented in default theme:

.\themes\default-bootstrap\js\global.js

with using class `.not_uniform`

> $("select.form-control,input[type='radio'],input[type='checkbox']").**not(".not_uniform")**.uniform();